# Identify movie/series involving space travel and supernatural entity

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation, wormhole

I vaguely remember a show that I once watched but I do not have enough elements to identify it and until now all my attempts have been unsuccessful.
I was probably drunk or high or both when I watched it, which is why my memories are scrappy and imprecise. Honestly, I am not completely sure that the show even exists or it is only something I imagined. Anyway, I am here to ask for help in figuring it out, if possible.

These are the things that I remember:
the show is an animation movie or series that takes place in space. There are spaceships, space travels and all the good stuff. Some kind of supernatural power or should I say "entity" is there. A giant space monster that travels freely across the galaxy.
At a certain point, the ships where the main action happens, incurs in some kind of space fracture or wormhole that takes it to another level of space time, something beyond the regular spacetime, where more of this supernatural "entities" are. There, the crew is taught about the real nature of the universe and of the supernatural entities.

Last piece of intel: I probably watched it on Netflix, but I am still unable to find any trace of it on the platform so... not sure about it.

That's it, I know it's not much and keep in mind that I was almost certainly very high: I do not exclude that I simply tripped on something I was watching and went far beyond the plot.

Answer (score 9):

Your description makes me think of [*Voltron: Legendary Defender*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltron:_Legendary_Defender), an animated series produced by Dreamworks and first aired on Netflix; the series comprises 8 seasons, released from 2016 to 2018.

It's a reboot of the [Voltron / GoLion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltron) from the 80s; while the main characters' names are the same, their characterization is often quite different, with the modern series being more nuanced and less of a monster-of-the-week mecha anime.

---

The details you remember could refer to episode S05E06 *"White Lion"*, the finale of the sixth season. The spaceship transporting the main characters arrives at a "white hole" that hides the location of a long-lost planet

[image: the spaceship arrives at the white hole]

There is a barrier only princess Allura and Lotor (head of the bad guys, apparently turned good) are able to enter; they find a temple-like structure

[image: Lotor and Allura before the temple entrance]

Here they are confronted by a white lion spirit

[image: the white lion]

and only the princess can advance and receive the knowledge and power they were looking for

[image: Allura receives the power of Altean alchemy]

---

Another possible match is episode S06E02 *"Razor's Edge"*: there are "space whales"

[image: space whales]

riding one of which a few characters enter a space-time anomaly

[image: space-time anomaly]

in a voyage that lasts two years (but just a few weeks for the other characters that did not enter the warped space).

<sub>(screenshots from https://thetvshows.us/index.php?cat=221)</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Could it be the [Final Space](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6317068/)?
It has giant space entities, special kind of universe beyond the main one, the titular Final Space.

Comment: I excluded Final Space from the start because I recall something less cartoonish and closer to the style of ID0 or Evangelion but I guess that a watch (or re-watch) is in order now. I'll let you know, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be Edens Zero? From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edens_Zero)

> set out to explore the universe by searching for Mother, the goddess of the cosmos

> causing a spacetime distortion that sent them 20,000 years into the future

> reveals that Mother can only be saved in Universe Zero, the
> convergence point of all parallel universes